# Excel VBA + Hide and/or Unhide Sheets via Array range

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple sheets in a workbook.

NotToTouchSheet1,NotToTouchSheet2,NotToTouchSheet3,NotToTouchSheet4,
HideOrToUnhideSheet1,HideOrToUnhideSheet2, ... ... ..., HideOrToUnhideSheet10

As you can see above, there's sheets that I do not want to hide no matter what happens, and sheets to hide or unhide given the condition.

The condition is, when a user choose a value from the combobox, the combobox listed out the sheet name which is spit out from the Array.

My question is, given the number of sheets that I have, how do I make it hide those that are Not in the range/array PLUS those that I do not want them to hide 'NotToTouchSheet'.

For example, a user choose 'A' from combobox list. 'A' value consist of HideOrToUnhideSheet1, HideOrToUnhideSheet3, HideOrToUnhideSheet5. Thus, I'd like 'NotToTouchSheet' sheets INCLUDING 'HideOrToUnhideSheet1,3 and 5' to show, and the rest to hide.

When a user choose 'B' from combobox list. 'B' value consist of HideOrToUnhideSheet8, HideOrToUnhideSheet9, HideOrToUnhideSheet10. Since, these sheets were hidden, I'd like to have it unhide, and to hide HideOrToUnhideSheet1,3 and 5.

I hope the above examples would helped you understand and visualize what I'd like to accomplish.

```
myArray = Split(blah, "|")

inputCell = 4


For Each sht In Worksheets
    For myArrayIndex = LBound(myArray) + 1 To UBound(myArray) - 1
        commName = Replace(myArray(myArrayIndex), " Consol", "")
        If (sht.Tab.Color = 192 Or sht.Tab.Color = 5296274) And (sht.Name Like "* Consol" Or sht.Name Like "* Detail") Then

        if the above condition is true, hide those sheets that are not in the array PLUS those 'NotToTouchSheet'

        End If

    Next myArrayIndex
Next sht
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve it by 'hiding' the sheets and then another loop to check if sheet is what I want to unhide.

```
myArray = Split(blah, "|")

inputCell = 4


For Each sht In Worksheets
    If (sht.Tab.Color = 192 Or sht.Tab.Color = 5296274) And (sht.Name Like "* Consol" Or sht.Name Like "* Detail") Then
        sht.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
Next sht


For Each cell In myArray
    If cell <> "" Then
        dtlCommName = Replace(cell, " Consol", " Detail")
        If Sheets(cell).Visible = xlSheetHidden Or Sheets(dtlCommName).Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
            Sheets(cell).Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheets(dtlCommName).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If

        Sheets("Consolidation Summary").Range("AB" & inputCell).Value = cell
        inputCell = inputCell + 1
    End If
Next cell
```